# Arduino Nano - Programmer not responding

Tags: arduino

I cannot seem to upload the simple blink program to my Arduino Nano. I keep getting the message:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03
```

What I have tried already with a lot of suggestions on Google. **I have tried it on both a Windows 7 & 8 machine and with 2 different Nano's**:

- Set my Board to Arduino Nano
- Set my Processor to ATmega168
- Set my port to COM1
- On windows 8 turned off driver signature
- Installed the FTDI Driver
- Checked my drivers in control panel

  - USB controllers says USB Serial Converter
  - USB Serial port says USB Serial Port (COM1)
- Rebooted a Lot!

When I plugin the nano to the USB it starts blinking the L led 180 times a minute. When I start uploading, L blinks at about 80-100 times a minute, blinks the rx and then start blinking the L led fast again.

Comment: I have the same problem and I did even try it with Windows XP, but no luck

Comment: It seemed to be the 'brand' of Nano. I send them back and asked Uno back. Worked perfectly! (In my case)

Answer (score 3):

As of 2018, if you have a genuine Nano (from Arduino), you could be getting this error because of an update to the bootloader on all Nanos shipped by Arduino after January 2018 (Read the note (highlighted in bold) here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoNano#toc4). You will have to update your `Arduino AVR Core` to 1.6.21 in `Boards Manager` Under `Tools -> Board` in the ArduinoIDE to use your shiny new Nano.

Conversely, if you have an older Nano (older than Jan 2018), but recently updated your ArduinoIDE, you should make sure the `Processor` you selected is `ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)` under `Tools -> Processor`.

If your Nano is not genuine (i.e. a 3rd Party Nano), then you may have to manually install the bootloader required to work with it. (The 3rd party should have documentation about this)